# ChatGPT en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy empezando el curso de openai en https://learn.deeplearning.ai/chatgpt-prompt-eng y no soy capaz de cargar la api.
Tengo este codigo:

````
import openai
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

openai.api_key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0, # this is the degree of randomness of the model's output
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]

text = f"""
You should express what you want a model to do by \ 
providing instructions that are as clear and \ 
specific as you can possibly make them. \ 
This will guide the model towards the desired output, \ 
and reduce the chances of receiving irrelevant \ 
or incorrect responses. Don't confuse writing a \ 
clear prompt with writing a short prompt. \ 
In many cases, longer prompts provide more clarity \ 
and context for the model, which can lead to \ 
more detailed and relevant outputs.
"""
prompt = f"""
Summarize the text delimited by triple backticks \ 
into a single sentence.
```{text}```
"""
response = get_completion(prompt)
print(response)
````

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

````
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthenticationError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7296\4286438876.py in 
     33 ```{text}```
     34 """
---> 35 response = get_completion(prompt)
     36 print(response)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7296\4286438876.py in get_completion(prompt, model)
      9 def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
     10     messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
---> 11     response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
     12         model=model,
     13         messages=messages,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openai\api_resources\chat_completion.py in create(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     23         while True:
     24             try:
---> 25                 return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
     26             except TryAgain as e:
     27                 if timeout is not None and time.time() > start + timeout:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py in create(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, request_id, api_version, organization, **params)
    147             url,
    148             params,
...
--> 186         raise openai.error.AuthenticationError(
    187             "No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = ', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = '. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details."
    188         )

AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = ', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = '. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.
````

Hay algo que puedo hacer ?? Ya probé a poner mi API key en la línea 7 pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 2):

El problema pasa porque el script no se está autenticando en ChatGPT: "*AuthenticationError: No API key provided*".
Veo que estás usando Windows, entonces accede a las [Variables de Entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+variables+de+entorno) y crea una nueva:

```
Variable Name: OPENAI_API_KEY
Variable Value: El_API_KEY_CREADO_EN_OPENAI_PUNTO_COM
```

Cierra todos los programas y los vuelves a abrir para que actualicen esa información.
En el código, la línea `openai.api_key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')` se queda así.
Con eso ya debe funcionar. Probé el código tal como lo pusiste y sirvió.

Si sigue saliendo el mensaje de "*Output exceeds the size limit*", es posible que sea un tema del IDE, prueba con [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72823258/1545868).

Comment: Me sigue dando error. No sé qué hago mal: RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.

Comment: Esto es otro error, y es bastante claro @Adrián , traducido sería: *Has excedido tu cuota actual, verifica tu plan y los detalles de facturación* En otras palabras, has gastado todo el crédito de uso del API que tenías con el plan actual. Debes introducir un pago o crear otro key (supongo que con otro usuario) para poder usarla gratuitamente.